# Probability: Even sum

Tags: probability

Out of a set of $\{1 ... 2n\}$ integers, we choose a sequence of length $n$, of integers
from the set.
(An element can be selected twice, order matters).

What is the probability that the sum of the sequence will be even?
How can I approach such problems?

Comment: For sequences of every length, assuming every element of the sequence except the last one is fixed, the parity of the last element determines the parity of the sum. Since the parity of the last element is uniformly distributed, the parity of the sum is uniformly distributed. Thus, the answer is: 50%.

Answer (score 4):

Our numbers are odd or even with equal probability. What they range over is irrelevant.

Let $p_n$ be the probability that a sequence of length $n$ has even sum. Then the probability that a sequence has odd sum is $1-p_n$.

Now look at sequences of length $n+1$. Such a sequence is obtained by appending an even or an odd to a sequence of length $n$. It can have even sum in two ways: (i) the old sum is even, and we appended an even or (ii) the old sum is odd, and we appended an odd. Thus
$$p_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}p_n+\frac{1}{2}(1-p_n)=\frac{1}{2},$$
and the required probability is always $\frac{1}{2}$.